# How to keep a value updated inside a TimelineMax?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I need that a function which gets me the value needed for a displacement to be executed every time the line is called.
If I use `line.play()` or `line.reverse()` the value is cached, and the function is not called. How can I make it call this function everytime ( but not re-creating the timeline altogether everytime)?

Here is the code:

```js
var line;

var getLeftPosition = function() {
    return ($("body").width() - $("#dvCart").width()) + "px";
}

$("#btnCart").click(function () {

    if (!line) {
        line = new TimelineMax()
            .to("#dvCart", .1, { display: "block" })
            .to("#dvLock", .7, {
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                opacity: 0.5,
                filter: "alpha(opacity=20)",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                top: "0",
                left: "0",
                position: "fixed",
                display: "block",
                ease: Power3.easeInOut
            })
            .to("#dvCart", .5, {
                "left": getLeftPosition(),
                ease: Power3.easeInOut
            });

        $("#dvLock").click(function () {
            line.reverse();
        });
    }
    else {
        line.play();
    }
});
```

To help the reading:

- when clicked a first time, I want it to initialize the timeline;
- every other time, it will just play the timeline;
- when the `dvLock` is clicked, the shopping cart needs to disappear;
- the `dvLock` is a div that is placed behind the cart, to lock the screen;
- the `dvCart`is a div that will contain a bunch of selected items;

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, it became clear how to search. After some googling around, I found a way to do it: using [updateTo](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/12080-how-to-use-tweenmaxupdateto-to-change-tovars-on-the-fly/) function on a TweenMax.

I am answering my question to help anyone who might need it.

The code became something like this:

```js
var line;

var getLeftPosition = function() {
    return ($("body").width() - $("#dvCart").width()) + "px";
}

var moveToLeft;

$("#btnCart").click(function () {

    if (!line) {

        line = new TimelineMax()
            .to("#dvLock", .1, { zIndex: 1031 })
            .to("#dvCart", .1, { display: "block" })
            .to("#dvLock", .7, {
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                opacity: 0.5,
                filter: "alpha(opacity=20)",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                top: "0",
                left: "0",
                position: "fixed",
                display: "block",
                ease: Power3.easeInOut
            })
            .append(moveToLeft = TweenMax.to("#dvCart", .5, {
                "left": getLeftPosition(),
                ease: Power3.easeInOut
            }));

        $("#dvLock").click(function () {
            moveToLeft.updateTo({
                "left": getLeftPosition()
            });
            line.reverse();
        });

    }
    else {
        moveToLeft.updateTo({
            "left": getLeftPosition()
        });
        line.play();
    }
});
```

So, before each `reverse` or `play`, it updates the left position.